# QuickBooks Inovice txnID changing

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I have an integration running that pulls invoices from QB via the web connector and stores them in SQL. It was always my understanding that the txnID was unique and would not change. I have recently ran into some issues where somehow a long the way some of the txnIDs are changing but it's the same invoice. The invoice number is the same but I end up with duplicates because we use txnID as the unique identifier.

I am not sure if there is just a bug in the code or if there is a case where the txnID will change but it's not actually a new invoice?

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TxnIDs do not change.

More than likely, what happened was an end-user deleted the invoice, and then re-created it with the same invoice number.

Did you try querying for the deleted transactions using TxnDeletedQuery to see if they were deleted?

Comment: Thanks Keith. I did not think it should change but I wanted to be sure. I have used the deleted transaction reports in QB but I did not know about that query. Thanks!